# NSBezierPath line thins out

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbezierpath

I'm trying to draw a power function curve in a 300x300 pixel rectangle using NSBezierPath as follows:

```
-(void)drawPowerCurve:(float)power points:(int)numbPoints{
    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth: 1.0];
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] set];

    NSPoint borderOrigin = {35.5,15.5};
    NSPoint endPoint;
    [path moveToPoint:borderOrigin];
    for(int i = 0; i < numbPoints; i++){
        endPoint.x = borderOrigin.x + (300.0/numbPoints)*(i+1);
        endPoint.y = borderOrigin.y + 300.0*pow(((i+1)/(float)numbPoints), power);
        [path lineToPoint:endPoint];
        [path stroke];
        [path moveToPoint:endPoint];
    }
}
```

However, the curve thins out at the top end compared to the bottom end.
For example power = 1.8 and numbPoints = 50.
Also the curve doesn't look as smooth as for example curves shown in Apple's ColorSync Utility. Of course I don't know how they are drawing the curves in ColorSync. Any ideas on how to improve the look of these curves (particularly getting rid of the thining out).

Edit -- Here is a screenshot: [image]

Comment: Please post a screen shot. Also, what is the height of the view (or graphics context) into which you're drawing?

Comment: Having a hard time pasting the screenshot on here -- it's a png file. However, I notice if I use many more points like 500 to 1000 rather than 50, the thining out is much less. Don't understand why that would be. Also, regarding graphics context, I'm not saving /restoring graphics context.

Comment: As a guess (sorry can't test at the moment) try moving the `stroke` out of the loop so you only draw the curve once instead of `numbPoints` times as it grows. You can also remove the redundant `moveToPoint` in the loop, `lineToPoint` leaves the current point at the end of the added segment.

Comment: @CRD That fixed it. The curve now looks identical to the curve in ColorSync. You could provide that as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `stroke` out of the loop so you only draw the curve once instead of `numbPoints` times as it grows. Also remove the redundant `moveToPoint` in the loop, `lineToPoint` leaves the current point at the end of the added segment.